# How to call the Async and Await in firestore

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function for get the data from firestore db.

### PlayerService.js

```
 //...
 async getHighestPlayers(game){
    const snapshot = await this.db
    .collection(game)
    .orderBy("score","asc")
    .limitToLast(1)
    .get();

    // What should I need to return ?

    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
      });
  }
```

### index.js

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  const  highestPlayers = playerService.getHighestPlayers("game1"); 
  res.render('index', { highestPlayers: highestPlayers});
});
```

How to make `async getHighestPlayers(game)` return , so I can call and use to display it result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't really said what exactly the template needs to render.  The template  will receive whatever you send.  If you're working with some spec to fulfill, you should covert the snapshot to whatever the client expects.  We don't have that information.

In the absence of a specification, you could simply send the entire contents of the matching document (if one was even found):

```
async getHighestPlayers(game) {
  const snapshot = this.db
    .collection(game)
    .orderBy("score","asc")
    .limitToLast(1)
    .get();

  if (snapshot.docs.length > 0) {
    return snapshot.docs[0].data();
  }
  else {
    return undefined;
  }
}
```

Then you will have to write some code to determine if there was actually a document present, and decide what you want to send if there was not:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  const highestPlayers = playerService.getHighestPlayers("game1"); 
  if (highestPlayers) {
    res.render('index', { highestPlayers: highestPlayers});
  }
  else {
    // what do you want to do if the document was missing?
  }
});
```

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, it's customary on Stack Overflow to accept it as correct using the checkmark button to the left.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add async-await to wait for `getHighestPlayers` to complete execution in `index.js`

```
router.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {
  const  highestPlayers = await playerService.getHighestPlayers("game1"); 
  res.render('index', { highestPlayers: highestPlayers});
});
```

changes in `getHighestPlayers`

```
async getHighestPlayers(game){
    const snapshot = await this.db
    .collection(game)
    .orderBy("score","asc")
    .limitToLast(1)
    .get();

    return snapshot;
  }
```

Comment: in func `getHighestPlayers` what should I need to return? or just return a snaphot?

Comment: @kn3l check the updated answer, if that works for you